# Searching files in NTFS

Tags: c#, search, wildcard, ntfs

We have a fairly large disk array with roughly 2-3 million XML files on it. The disk is formatted with NTFS and we would like to search the filesystem using wildcards. So something like * SomePartOfTheFilename * would be a typical search query.

We are using .Net and are finding that using DirectoryInfo appears to be slow.

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

List<FileInfo> fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles(searchString, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Using  Loops and recursion is also very slow.

Is there a lower level API call we can use to directly search the NTFS index?

Using dir * SomePartOfTheFilename * /s from the command line is almost instant. Is there something there that can be leveraged?

Comment: Does a _find_ in cygwin also finish quickly, or is it similar to your .net code speed?  If so, its probably some super secret MS integration between cmd.exe and pre-built indexes.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you've not built an external index, either using Indexing Services (as pointed out below) or some home brew solution?  Not only is searching a file system slow for you, but you have a chance of slowing down the work others are doing if the disk heads end up thrashing around trying to service the competing requests...

Comment: We were hoping to rely on the NTFS index to be fast enough, we may well create our own index to the files but wanted to explore other options first.

Comment: I've taken to simply creating a text file (think: dir /s /b C:\ > filelist.txt) to use as an index. I've found Windows (on win7) file indexing to be terribly slow and often unreliable. Far too often the Windows index fails to find files I know are there, and I have to force a rebuild to fix the problem. Grepping through a text file is fast and reliable, though it is hardly ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use the Indexing service, but it may be handy for what you are trying to do:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Indexing_Service_HOW-TO.aspx

It allows you to create complex queries against the NTFS index of the files on a computer.

Comment: Hi Scott

Thanks for the idea, although I am not sure the indexing service will be appropriate here. I think the indexing service creates an index of the file contents as well as the filenames because of this I think we will end up with an enormous index. Our disk is around 500Gb.

We are only interested in searching the filenames. I wonder if it is possible to configure the index service to only index the filenames?-Need to have a look...

Answer (score 1):

You may use MFT directly (See: [NTFS Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)). That is data table where all information about files is located. You can see the structure of MFT for example [here](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-mft.htm) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/MftRead.aspx). The Windows API ends up in the same table so you can alternatively try to speed the searches up to guarantee that it will be paged in memory before search (simple read of e.g. c:\$Mft is enough).